# Hudson slaves failing to start on Windows XP: java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: hudson

I have bug troubles (re)starting Hudson slaves on Windows XP machines that are located on a different campus (not so close to the hudson server, still the network speed is decent and reliable - do get ~400-800 KB/s on test).

Hudson server is running on OS X under Tomcat.

`hudson-slave.err.log`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.Launcher.runAsTcpServer(Launcher.java:303)
at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:202)
at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:167)
```

`hudson-slave.wrapper.log`:

```
2010-10-11 12:22:18 - Started 3116
2010-10-12 00:52:11 - Starting javaw.exe -Xrs -jar "d:\.hudson\slave.jar" -tcp         d:\.hudson\port.txt
2010-10-12 00:52:12 - Started 3312
2010-10-12 02:12:05 - Starting javaw.exe -Xrs -jar "d:\.hudson\slave.jar" -tcp     d:\.hudson\port.txt
2010-10-12 02:12:05 - Started 1332
2010-10-12 02:36:05 - Starting javaw.exe -Xrs -jar "d:\.hudson\slave.jar" -tcp d:\.hudson\port.txt
2010-10-12 02:36:05 - Started 2972
2010-10-12 03:56:05 - Starting javaw.exe -Xrs -jar "d:\.hudson\slave.jar" -tcp d:\.hudson\port.txt
2010-10-12 03:56:05 - Started 632
```

Event log:

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   hudsonslave-d__.hudson
Event Category: None
Event ID:   0
Date:       10/12/2010
Time:       3:56:36 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   GWATANAB370-XP
Description:
Child process [632 - javaw.exe -Xrs -jar "d:\.hudson\slave.jar" -tcp d:\.hudson\port.txt] terminated with 1
```

Another strange thing is that I see that `slave.jar` file is always incomplete. The one from the server is `131131` bytes long but the one downloaded to the client is always less than this.

On the node monitor the last step is `Copying slave.jar` and stays like this forever.

In case it wasn't obvious the node is configured to be started with `Let Hudson control this Windows slave as a Windows service` option. This seams to me the most reliable method that should be safe even if hudson server or client is rebooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have good experience with installing a slave as a service and let the remote machine handle the service startup and shutdown. Master and slave find each other regardless of what server gets restarted. Works reliable and I don't need to supply a Administrator password to control the slave.

As you probably figured out, you need to update the slave together with the master. But I don't remember if I always did this. Meanwhile we switched the slaves to unix and I use the ssh feature. The slaves come only up when needed. So I can't really run a test with this.